# Erro NullPointerException na execução

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Olá. Mais uma vez estou tendo erro de  NullPointerException. Não consigo identificar porque.

A Atividade é a seguinte :

> Crie um aplicativo Java para controlar o cardápio semanal de pacientes de uma Clínica de Nutrição. Você deverá considerar a criação de duas classes, sendo:
>
> Classe Refeição: contém a descrição da refeição, bem como as informações de valor calórico, custo aproximado e tipo da refeição. O tipo da refeição é uma classificação estabelecida pela clínica, conforme:
>
> Diet;
>
> Equilibrada;
>
> Light;
>
> Low carb;
>
> Low fat;
>
> Natural;
>
> Sem glúten;
>
> Vegano;
>
> Vegetariano;
>
> Classe Cardápio: que deverá conter o cardápio semanal, com 6 refeições diárias.
>
> Crie uma classe Teste (com o método main()) para gerar um cardápio semanal que calcule o custo e valor calórico diários e semanal do cardápio.
>
> Observações importantes:
>
> Para implementar o tipo das refeições, considere a criação de um array estático na classe Refeição com os valores acima descritos.
>   Na classe Cardápio, implemente as operações de manipulação do array bidimensional (incluir, alterar, percorrer, e etc).
>   Excepcionalmente nesse projeto, o método de exibição do cardápio semanal da classe Cardápio poderá exibir mensagens na console. Evite fazer isso nos demais métodos e nas demais classes, exceto na classe de Teste.

Classe RestauranteTeste:

```
public class RestauranteTeste {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Cardapio semana = new Cardapio();

        semana.incluirRefeicao();


    }//end main method    


}//end class RestauranteTeste
```

Classe Refeicao:

```
package projeto_4;

public class Refeicao {

    //Atributos da Classe
    private String descricao;
    private int caloria;
    private double custo;
    private int tipoDeRefeicao;

    //atributo estatico inicializado com os valores pedidos
    public static String[] classificacao = {"Diet", "Equilibrada", "Light", "Low carb",  "Low fat", "Natural", "Sem glúten", "Vegano", "Vegetariano"};

    /**** Metodos set e get ****/ 

    //descricao
    public void setDescricao(String descricao){

        this.descricao = descricao;
    }//end method setDescricao

    public String getDescricao(){

        return this.descricao;
    }//end method getDescricao

    //caloria
    public void setCaloria(int caloria){

        this.caloria = caloria;
    }//end method setCaloria

    public int getCaloria(){

        return this.caloria;
    }//end method getCaloria


    //custo
    public void setCusto(double custo){

        this.custo = custo;
    }//end method setCaloria

    public double getCusto(){

        return this.custo;
    }//end method getCaloria    

    //tipoDeRefeicao
    public void setTipoDeRefeicao(int tipoDeRefeicao){

        this.tipoDeRefeicao = tipoDeRefeicao;
    }//end method setTipoDeRefeicao

    public String getTipoDeRefeicao(){

        return classificacao[(tipoDeRefeicao-1)];
    }//end method getTipoDeRefeicao

}
```

classe Cardapio:

```
package projeto_4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cardapio {

    private Refeicao[][] menu;

    public Cardapio(){

      this.menu = new Refeicao[6][7];

    }//end contructor

    public void incluirRefeicao(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i, j;

        for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {

            System.out.printf("Digite a descrição da refeição: ");
            String strReceber = input.nextLine();
            menu[i][j].setDescricao(strReceber);

            System.out.printf("Digite a caloria: ");
            int intReceber = input.nextInt();
            menu[i][j].setCaloria(intReceber);

            System.out.printf("Digite o Custo: ");
            double floatReceber = input.nextDouble();
            menu[i][j].setCusto(floatReceber);

            System.out.printf("Digite o Tipo de refeição: ");
            intReceber = input.nextInt();
            menu[i][j].setTipoDeRefeicao(intReceber);



            }//end for(j = 0; j < 7; j++)


        }//end for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)


    }//end method incluirRefeicao


    public void listarMenu(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i, j;

        for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {

            System.out.printf("Digite a descrição da refeição: %s", 
                    menu[i][j].getDescricao() );


            System.out.printf("Digite a caloria: %d",
                    menu[i][j].getCaloria() );


            System.out.printf("Digite o Custo: %.02f",
                    menu[i][j].getCusto() );


            System.out.printf("Digite o Tipo de refeição: %s",
                    menu[i][j].getTipoDeRefeicao() );




            }//end for(j = 0; j < 7; j++)


        }//end for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)


    }//end method listarMenu

    //linha][coluna

    public void alteraRefeicao(int linha, int coluna){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Digite a descrição da refeição: ");
            String strReceber = input.nextLine();
            menu[linha][coluna].setDescricao(strReceber);

            System.out.printf("Digite a caloria: ");
            int intReceber = input.nextInt();
            menu[linha][coluna].setCaloria(intReceber);

            System.out.printf("Digite o Custo: ");
            double floatReceber = input.nextDouble();
            menu[linha][coluna].setCusto(floatReceber);

            System.out.printf("Digite o Tipo de refeição: ");
            intReceber = input.nextInt();
            menu[linha][coluna].setTipoDeRefeicao(intReceber);

    }//end alteraRefeicao




}//end class Cardapio
```

Erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at projeto_4.Cardapio.incluirRefeicao(Cardapio.java:28)
>       at projeto_4.RestauranteTeste.main(RestauranteTeste.java:11)
>   /home/aluno/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 4 segundos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que inicializar o elementos do seu *array*

Exemplo:

```
class Elemento {
    private String atributo;
    public void setAtributo(String atributo) {
        this.atributo = atributo;
    }
    public String getAtributo() {
        return atributo;
    }
}

class Elementos {
    private Elemento[][] elementos;

    public Elementos () {
        elementos = new Elemento[6][7];

        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {

            System.out.println(elementos[i]);
            for(j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (elementos[i][j] == null) {
                    elementos[i][j] = new Elemento();
                }
                elementos[i][j].setAtributo(String.format("Elemento [%d][%d]", i, j));
                System.out.println(elementos[i][j].getAtributo());
            }
        }
    }
}

class Teste {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("inicio");
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(String.format("arg: '%s'", arg));
        }

        Elementos Elementos = new Elementos();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Implementei usando seu exemplo como base.

Answer (score 2):

Note que o seu *array* foi somente definido no trecho:

```
public Cardapio() {
    this.menu = new Refeicao[6][7];
}// end contructor
```

Porém, além disso, você ainda precisa inicializar as instâncias que irão ocupar essas posições. Um simples ajuste seria ajustar a sua classe para:

```
public class Cardapio {

private Refeicao[][] menu;
public Cardapio() {
    this.menu = new Refeicao[6][7];
}// end contructor

public void incluirRefeicao() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (Objects.isNull(menu[i][j])) // Verificar se esta posição ainda não tem um objeto instanciado
                menu[i][j] = new Refeicao(); // Caso não exista, instancia uma nova referência
            System.out.printf("Digite a descrição da refeição: ");
            String strReceber = input.nextLine();
            menu[i][j].setDescricao(strReceber);

            System.out.printf("Digite a caloria: ");
            int intReceber = input.nextInt();
            menu[i][j].setCaloria(intReceber);

            System.out.printf("Digite o Custo: ");
            double floatReceber = input.nextDouble();
            menu[i][j].setCusto(floatReceber);

            System.out.printf("Digite o Tipo de refeição: ");
            intReceber = input.nextInt();
            menu[i][j].setTipoDeRefeicao(intReceber);
        } // end for(j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    } // end for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
}// end method incluirRefeicao

public void listarMenu() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            System.out.printf("Digite a descrição da refeição: %s", menu[i][j].getDescricao());
            System.out.printf("Digite a caloria: %d", menu[i][j].getCaloria());
            System.out.printf("Digite o Custo: %.02f", menu[i][j].getCusto());
            System.out.printf("Digite o Tipo de refeição: %s", menu[i][j].getTipoDeRefeicao());
        } // end for(j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    } // end for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
}// end method listarMenu

// linha][coluna

public void alteraRefeicao(int linha, int coluna) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Digite a descrição da refeição: ");
    String strReceber = input.nextLine();
    menu[linha][coluna].setDescricao(strReceber);

    System.out.printf("Digite a caloria: ");
    int intReceber = input.nextInt();
    menu[linha][coluna].setCaloria(intReceber);

    System.out.printf("Digite o Custo: ");
    double floatReceber = input.nextDouble();
    menu[linha][coluna].setCusto(floatReceber);

    System.out.printf("Digite o Tipo de refeição: ");
    intReceber = input.nextInt();
    menu[linha][coluna].setTipoDeRefeicao(intReceber);
}// end alteraRefeicao
}// end class Cardapio
```

Comment: Olá. Implementei com a ideia do @Sósthenes Neto. Mas mesmo assim obrigado. Não da pra marcar sua resposta como relevante pq não tenho reputação suficiente pra fazer isso ainda :(  Depois vou tentar usar o 'if (Objects.isNull(menu[i][j]))' pq achei legal.

Comment: @ThiagoSoaresMota Você pode votar +1 em todas as respostas que achar úteis.